# KCFinder web file manager with TinyMCE, Php script not working

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce, file-browser

I'm using KCFinder with TinyMCE in my MVC3 application. My configuration looks like as follows

```
tinyMCE.init({
    file_browser_callback: 'openKCFinder',
    ...........
    ...........
});

function openKCFinder(field_name, url, type, win) {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=tinymce&type=' + type,
        title: 'KCFinder',
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        resizable: "yes",
        inline: true,
        close_previous: "no",
        popup_css: false
    }, {
        window: win,
        input: field_name
    });
    return false;
}
```

Here, when I Click on Image browser in TinyMCE window, It calls the URL `'/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=tinymce&type=' + type'`

But, Problem is, Instead of executing this `browse.php` file, It's downloading the same file...

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks as if your webserver isn't configured correctly. Make sure it is able to interpret `php` files. Do you use any other php script that are accessible?

Comment: this depends on your webserver, which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using MVC 3 in windows 7 OS. might be it's ISS

Comment: i am not used to MVC. using windows you need to install php explicitly. is it installed?

Comment: PHP is installed and Configured in IIS

Comment: good, what happens if you open another php file on your server?

Comment: this looks as if the server has been able to process the file, but encountered an error (probably in the php code). can you try another php file?

Comment: This answer is correct. @ShreekumarS OP, please accept reply :)